# Can't calculate of the total sales of the day form my code, everytime it shows zero(0)

Tags: java, arraylist, product

So, I wrote this code and its working fine but when i try to check total sale it shows zero(0).
in this part-

```
public void totalSales(){
                getTotal();
               System.out.println("Total sales is "+getTotal());
            }.
```

I am struggling to save the previous values to get the total sales. And also how do I take multiple input from the menu? Any kind of help would be appreciated. If you see an area of improvement, do let me know. Thank You!

```
import `java.util.InputMismatchException`;
import java.util.Scanner;
import `java.util.ArrayList`;

public class Main {
    
    static double a;
    ArrayList<Product> cart = new ArrayList<Product> ();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double vat = 0.5;
    boolean done = false;

    public Main() {
            cart.add(new Product("Vegetable", 8.00));
            cart.add(new Product("Deodrant", 56.00));
            cart.add(new Product("Beverages", 35.00));
            cart.add(new Product("Home Essentials", 10.00));
            cart.add(new Product("Bakery", 20.50));
            cart.add(new Product("Snacks", 15.00));
        }

        public void displayCart() {
            for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
                switch (cart.get(i).quantitySelected){
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(i + ": " + cart.get(i).name + "   Not Selected.");
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    System.out.println(i + ": " + cart.get(i).name + "   Selected: " + cart.get(i).quantitySelected);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void addToCart(int product, int amount) {
            cart.get(product).select(amount);
        }

        public void getSelection() {

            int productSelected;

            System.out.println("Enter the Product Value: \nOr \nEnter Done to End and See The Total. ");

            try {
                productSelected = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                done = true;
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter Amount To Select: ");
            int amount = scanner.nextInt();
            cart.get(productSelected).select(amount);
        }
        
        public double getSubtotal() {
            double cost = 0.00;
            for (Product product : cart) {
                cost += product.cost * product.quantitySelected;
            }
            return cost;
        }
           
        public double getTotal() {
            return (getSubtotal() + getSubtotal()*vat);
                  
        }
            public void totalSales(){
                getTotal();
               System.out.println("Total sales is "+getTotal());
            }
        
        public void finnishPurchase() {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("Subtotal: " + getSubtotal());
            System.out.println("Vat: " + vat);
            System.out.println("Total: " + getTotal());
                
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main store = new Main();
            while (!store.done) {
                store.displayCart();
                store.getSelection();
            }
            store.finnishPurchase();
                System.out.println("Enter the password");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String pw=input.next();
        String actual="abc123";
        boolean check=pw.equals(actual);
        if(check==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Correct password.Here is the access");
            Main c=new Main();
            c.totalSales();
          
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect password.Try again");
        }
                
        }
         
    }

public class Product {
    String name;
    double cost;

    int quantitySelected = 0;

    public Product(String name, double cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
  
    }

    public void select(int quantity) {
        quantitySelected = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Without SQL or Database

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). It seems that you have not made an attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: I did but it shows error. I even wrote to get the total sales but during output it shows 0.

Comment: In your question, you wrote "I am stuck in these parts" without elaborating about how exactly you are stuck. You have not defined any errors or described your attempts.

Comment: I might've lfted it out on the question, this part (given later) gives 0.0, i can't get the total sales, everytime i put an input, it just shows zero- public void totalSales(){
                getTotal();
               System.out.println("Total sales is "+getTotal());
            }

Comment: If you left it out in the question, edit your question and elaborate on your issues. Please be very specific.

Comment: I have done it, THANK YOU.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by multiple inputs from the menu?

Comment: What I meant by multiple input in the menu was that I want to know how I could take several 2/3 product values at the same time and record the total sales, instead of one by one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your total issue.
You start a new main for no reason which resets the total to 0.
[image]
The fix was just to use the old main(Check the environment i tested in) to get the total.

[image]

I don't understand what you mean by getting mutiple inputs from the menu, however, it loops fine to select products one by one. I adapted the code to limit the number of  products. All I did was add a limit variable to each object(you can use static to add a global limit). If you wanted to retrieve all users' totals you would have to store them then retrieve them and add them up.

[The code I made.](https://www.online-java.com/PrCApnG5Uv)

### Edit:

In order to take multiple item you just have to loop your nextInt() statements.

#### Code(Main.java):

```
System.out.println("Enter the Products and amounts(eg. 1(product) 20(amount)) Value: \nOr \nEnter Done to End and See The Total. ");
        while(true){
            try {
                productSelected = scanner.nextInt();
                int amount = scanner.nextInt();
                if((amount+cart.get(productSelected).quantitySelected) <= cart.get(productSelected).limit)
                    cart.get(productSelected).select(amount);
                else
                    System.out.println("Limit reached for item:"+cart.get(productSelected).name);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                done = true;
                return;
            }
        }
```

The menu won't redisplay the user menu and will wait for the user to put done(or the wrong input). The user is able to put products line by line or all in one line(eg. 1 10 2 5 done) and get their total(check the code I tested on).

Comment: Thank You for your help. I was able to fix it later on. What I meant by multiple input in the menu was that I want to know how I could take several 2/3 product values at the same time and record the total sales, instead of one by one.

Comment: All you have to do is loop your scanner.nextInt() to take multiple inputs. I'll put the code changes in my answer.

Comment: You also might want to consider refactoring your code for efficiency.